# Teams and PVA Adaptive Card Compatibility with 1.4

Tags: adaptive-cards

The new features of adaptive cards in v 1.3 and 1.4 (especially being able to replace a card as part of an execute action)  are awesome.

Does anyone know when teams and PVA will be able to handle these newer versions ? After having watched some of the Microsoft videos and adaptive cards schema, it looks like this compatibility had been planned to already be available.

I am new to adaptive cards - a wonderful concept. I am developing bots using framework composer extension to PVA.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: The new feature are not yet available as far as i know but scheduled for the next month.

Answer (score 0):

We are also excited about ACv1.4! I had a look at the [roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Microsoft%20Teams) but I don't see anything related to Adaptive Cards in the pipeline.